# How can I force youtube to autoplay in the highest quality (fmt=22)

Tags: youtube, spam-prevention

For example if I do a youtube search for a "random video" I get directed to a url like:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pXfHLUlZf4
```

When where I really want to end up is:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pXfHLUlZf4&fmt=22
```

Is there any easy way to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't if they aren't available! Other than that you can choose in your profile to always show videos in the highest quality available:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have Firefox and GreaseMonkey, or Opera at all, use this userscript: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/41212

Answer (score 1):

If you're logged into youtube, there's an option to always play high quality videos. If you go to settings you'll find the option here.

Comment: Doesn't play it in the fmt=22 format, whoever upvoted this didn't read the question.